# Tkinter (python 2.7.2) Help needed

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

I'm trying to make my first GUI program. The problem is, that I can't figure out how to make a main menu, which would switch to one of the programs after clicking a button.

```
#Dev by Mkee
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
#Main Stuff
app = Tk()
app.title("Mkee's Tools")
app.geometry('300x200')

#modules
class Programs:
    def Shuffle():
        app2 = Tk()
        app2.title("Shuffle")
        app2.geometry('300x200')
        app2.mainloop()


#end of modules

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set('')
label1 = Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

button1 = Button(app, text='Shuffle', width=30, command=Programs.Shuffle)
button1.pack(side='right', padx=5,pady=1)


app.mainloop()
```

I know that I'm doing it wrong. I just have no idea how to do it, So i gave it a try of how could it be. Please help me.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at a better GUI toolkit? PyQt4 is quite nice.

Comment: @Blender: "better" is subjective. Tkinter is quite good for most problems, especially when one is first learning. For those of us with lots of experience under our belt, tkinter continues to be a very viable choice. In fact, just today I decided to scrap a project I've been doing in wxPython in favor of tkinter. Tkinter is modern, well supported, cross platform, and very easy to use.

Comment: @Byran: Sure, "better" is subjective. I was only suggesting PyQt4 because it draws native-looking UI elements and was easier to work with (for me) than Tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could call [pack_forget()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method) to hide widgets, and (later)
   `pack` to show them again:
2. Tkinter is singled-threaded, and `mainloop` runs the main event loop. Therefore you shouldn't call `mainloop` twice.

---

```
#Dev by Mkee
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

class Shuffle(object):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master=master
        self.text=tk.Text(master)
    def hide(self):
        self.text.pack_forget()
    def show(self):
        self.text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

class Buttons(object):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master=master
        self.red = tk.Button(self.master, text="Red", bg="red", fg="white")
        self.green = tk.Button(self.master, text="Green", bg="green", fg="black")
        self.blue = tk.Button(self.master, text="Blue", bg="blue", fg="white")
    def hide(self):
        self.red.pack_forget()
        self.green.pack_forget()
        self.blue.pack_forget()                
    def show(self):
        self.red.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.green.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.blue.pack(side=tk.LEFT,expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.BOTH)

class MainApp(object):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master=master
        app=self.app=tk.Tk()
        app.title("Mkee's Tools")
        app.geometry('300x200')
        self.shuffle=Shuffle(master)
        self.buttons=Buttons(master)
        self.current=None
        menubar=tk.Menu(app)
        program_menu=tk.Menu(menubar)
        program_menu.add_command(label='Shuffle',
                                 command=lambda: self.show(self.shuffle))
        program_menu.add_command(label='Buttons',
                                 command=lambda: self.show(self.buttons)) 
        program_menu.add_command(label='Quit',command=sys.exit) 
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Programs', menu=program_menu)
        app.config(menu=menubar)
    def show(self,obj):
        if self.current != obj:
            try: self.current.hide()
            except AttributeError: pass
            self.current=obj
            obj.show()

def main():
    m=MainApp()
    m.app.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the effect that I wanted to get. What I want to get is when you hit the button, "Shuffle" opens up in the same window, not by popping out a different window.
Actually, the menu bar Is good. But is it possible to make it run in the same window instead of the "popup"?